# Can I change a Lemma to a Proposition?

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

I am getting confused about one thing:

I am reading a paper say X. Paper X has a Lemma in it. I am also writing a paper for my dissertation. I want to use the Lemma from Paper X in proving a  theorem in my paper.

While quoting Lemma from paper X, do I need to state the Lemma as **Lemma** in my dissertation, or I can write it as a **Proposition**.

My question is simple: While citing a **Lemma** from a paper, is it required to call it as **Lemma** in my dissertation too?
Or I can cite the **Lemma** but name it as **Proposition** in my paper?

If someone could tell me what is the standard procedure here, I shall be grateful.

Comment: @ryang; your answer has been accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cite Lemma 2.3 from paper X, and, when quoting it, write it as Proposition 8.7.

For [example](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?&q=%22which+we+reproduce+here+as%22+theorem+OR+proposition+OR+lemma):

“...<in-text citation of Lemma 2.3> (which we reproduce here as Proposition 8.7).”

Comment: Is it allowed and natural in mathematical literature? Can you please let me know the correct way to do it by showing an example

Comment: @Charlotte Yes, there's no single correct way, since this is a matter of style. I just added an example above.